# flex - access linkbutton outside the datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I am using this code:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn id="test" headerText="Case ID" width="80">
  <mx:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
      <mx:Canvas>
        <mx:LinkButton id="lnkCaseId" click="lnkCaseId.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK,true,false))" label="{data.caseId}" textDecoration="underline" color="#0052A5">
        </mx:LinkButton>
      </mx:Canvas>
    </fx:Component>
  </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

How can I access **lnkCaseId** outside the datagrid?

Comment: can you describe for what purpose you wants to outside grid, it would be help full, also its has multiple instance i.e. individual instance for each row.

Comment: @Imran .. on creationComplete event of application i want to add an eventlistener for linkbutton.

Comment: see ans for how to add event listener to in linerendrere

Comment: possible duplicate of [flex - get linkbutton label name and selected row of datagrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978176/flex-get-linkbutton-label-name-and-selected-row-of-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

You can add external-document event-listener to  [Inline renderers](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html) using outerdocument method

```
<mx:LinkButton label="Buy" click="{outerDocument.outerFileMethod(data)}" />
```

Another way of getting rendrer is by event bubbling please see sample below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
    click="{clicked(event)}">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.LinkButton;
            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            public function clicked(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if (event.target is LinkButton)
                {
                    var innerLinkButon:LinkButton = event.target as LinkButton;
                    Alert.show("Application : "+innerLinkButon.label);
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:DataGrid id="grid">
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:ArrayCollection>
                <mx:Array>
                    <mx:Object label="AAAA"/> 
                    <mx:Object label="BBBB"/>
                    <mx:Object label="CCCC"/>
                    <mx:Object label="DDDD"/>
                </mx:Array>
            </mx:ArrayCollection>
        </mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn id="columnA" headerText="columnA" dataField="@label">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:LinkButton click="{clicked(event)}" label="{data.label.toString()}">
                            <mx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    import mx.controls.Alert;

                                    public function clicked(event:MouseEvent):void
                                    {
                                        Alert.show("linkButton");
                                    }

                                ]]>
                            </mx:Script>
                        </mx:LinkButton>
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: i hv tried this but i hv refused to use outerDocument http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978176/flex-get-linkbutton-label-name-and-selected-row-of-datagrid

Comment: i have place a sample in ans for event bubbling